# Proving Fibonacci recursive algorithm time complexity

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, time-complexity, fibonacci

I am trying to understand a proof by induction in my algorithms text book. Here's the author is proving using induction that the T(n) will always be greater than 2^(n/2) (This is for calculating the nth fibonacci number using the recursive algorithm):
[image]

What I don't understand is the very last step, where he is manipulating the equation. How does he go from:

```
> 2^(n-1)/2 + 2^(n-2)/2 +1
```

to

```
> 2^(n-2)/2 + 2^(n-2)/2 +1
```

He just randomly changes  `2^(n-1)/2`  to `2^(n-2)/2`. Is this a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that particular step runs off the assumption that:

```
T(n-1) > T(n-2)
```

Therefore, we can form an algebraic inequality:

```
T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1 > T(n-2) + T(n-2) + 1
```

We can lop off the + 1 from the right side (because the inequality will still hold true for anything subtracted away on the LESSER side):

```
T(n-1) + T(n-2) + 1 > T(n-2) + T(n-2)
```

From this, substitute our T(m) = 2^(m/2) (for anything less than n and > 2, which n-1 and n-2 both qualify):

```
2^(n-1)/2 + 2^(n-2)/2 + 1 > 2^(n-2)/2 + 2^(n-2)/2
```

That gets you that particular step. It's done this way deliberately as the poster above me stated, to get to 2^(n/2).

Answer (score 5):

It's deliberate, if you look closely it's an inequation and he uses it do finish the induction step.

Note the typo, it should say "We must show that T(n) > 2^(n/2)" and not <.